# ¿Cómo convertir undefined a string?

Tags: javascript, string, undefined

Intenté esto, pero no me sirve:

```js
function e(n) {
  if(typeof n == 'undefined') {
    return n.toString();
  }
  else {
    return n;
  }
}

console.log(e(socket));
```

Sé que el error es que el parámetro enviado se toma como si se enviara una variable pero, ¿no hay nada que hacer? Porque yo lo quiero solucionar desde dentro de la función

Comment: `socket` se toma como variable que no existe , por lo tanto saltará error de variable no definida y muere la ejecución.  **Una cosa es lo que envía a la función y otra lo que recibe la función**.

Comment: **Una variable a la que no se le ha asignado valor es de tipo undefined.** No tiene sentido intentar convertir la variable a otro tipo de dato, ya que no está definida.

Answer (score 2):

En el ejemplo que planteas la variable `socket` **no existe**, esto nos mostrara un error en la ejecucion.

Se deberia omitir la variable socket, y podrias hacer algo como esto:

```js
function e(n) {

  if (typeof n == 'undefined') {
    return typeof n;
  } else {
    return n;
  }

}

console.log(e());
```

Lo que ocurre con el ejemplo que has planteado es que la funcion typeof, reconoce una variable indefinida, siempre y cuando esta no se pase como un parametros.

Mira esta linea:

```
console.log(e(socket));
```

Le estas indicando que la funcion se ejecute teniendo de parametro la variable socket, la cual no existe.

Pero si la ejecutas de esta manera:

```
console.log(e());
```

Como no estas pasando ningun parametro, la funcion typeof reconocera que no se paso ningun parametro y por lo tanto retornara "undefined".

Comment: lo que pasa es que, quiero que transforme socket a una socket como string DENTRO DE LA FUNCION

Comment: Quieres es retornar el nombre de la variable como cadena?

Comment: Si exactamente¡

Answer (score 1):

Quizás te sirva esto:

```
function e(n) {
    return n ? n : '';
}
```

O de esta otra forma:

```
function e(n) {
    return (typeof n == 'undefined') ? '' : n
}
```

En la primera versión, si recibes un valor false también devuelve cadena vacía. Y quizás eso no es lo que buscas. De la segunda manera solo cuando el parámetro es `undefined` se devuelve una cadena vacía, o el valor del parámetro en caso contrario incluido el valor `null`.

Comment: ¿Podrías aportar algún tipo de explicación para hacer la respuesta más útil?

Comment: Creo que es un código tan sencillo que ya es autoexplicativo. De todas formas, si la función recibe un parámetro con valor definido devuelve dicho valor, de lo contrario (no se le envía parámetro, o se le envía null o undefined) devuelve un string vacío.

Comment: Sí, entiendo lo del operador ternario :) Yo habría hecho `if n: return n; return ''`. Por cierto, mejor pon la explicación en el cuerpo de la pregunta dándole a [edit]. Los comentarios se van con el viento...

Comment: Más sencillo aún: `return n || '';`

Comment: Sí @fedorqui, ya supuse que tu si entiendes lo del operador ternario. Puse la explicación porque me aconsejaste que la pusiera, supongo que para la comprensión general. Dicho esto, me doy cuenta que la respuesta que dí, o la más comprimida aún propuesta por @carlos-a-gómez tiene el problema de que si se le envía como parámetro el valor booleano `false` devuelve una cadena vacía. Según la pregunta quizás sería mejor hacerlo de otra forma que pasaré a poner en la respuesta

Comment: Pues sin entrar en si es la mejor respuesta o no (no sé lo suficiente de JavaScript), has acabado publicando una respuesta la mar de razonada y explicada. ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: jajaja sí, eso parece. Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Si la variable es undefined, es que no tiene un contenido asignado, intentar transformarla a string (a mi punto de vista) no tendría lógica pero tampoco se el motivo por el que querrías hacer eso.

Si es que un js te esta dando error porque intentas imprimir y te dice que es undefined y según lo que quieres hacer tendría que tener un contenido revisa el código, para asegurarte que si le estas asignando un valor.

Si lo que quieres es que si no esta definida se convierta en un string vacío, como comentaba un compañero antes:

```
function e(n) {
    return n ? n : '';
}
```

Algo así te podría funcionar.